# mybatis builder exception The expression 'room' evaluated to a null value

Tags: mybatis

gomap_controller.java

```
List<String> room = new ArrayList<String>();
Map searchConditions = new HashMap<>();
searchConditions.put("room", room);
List<Map> rList = rd.getRoomList(searchConditions);
```

room-mapper.xml

```
<select id="getRoomList" resultType="java.util.HashMap"
        parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
<choose>
            <when
                test="underground != '' or low_floor != '' or mid_floor != '' or high_floor != ''">
                B_FLOOR IN
                <foreach collection="room" item="item" index="index"
                    separator="," open="(" close=")AND">
                    #{item}
                </foreach>
            </when>
        </choose>
```

and now I getting error as 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: The expression 'room' evaluated to a null value.

Comment: in your snippet room list is empty, empty/null might trigger the same error (although I expect empty to skip the  loop). You can add tests such as: `<if test="room == null">room is null</if>` ... whatever result SQL is invalid, this is debugging.

Comment: yes but its not empty. I checked it before it passing it.

Comment: better use most abstract type possible: `resultType="map" parameterType="map"`, not necessarily related, but one never knows

Comment: it keep telling me "### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: The expression 'room' evaluated to a null value.
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: The expression 'room' evaluated to a null value."

Comment: is there something else to check ?

Comment: getting ? values ### SQL: select * from room where   B_FLOOR IN    (          ?    ,         ?    ,         ?    )

Comment: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='type', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null for parameter #1 with JdbcType OTHER . Try setting a different JdbcType for this

Comment: Edit  question to provide with whole code snippet, I cannot guess.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your test are you evaluating for a null collection. It looks like you're executing validations on keys in the map? Based on the small snippet of code you have there I would expect to see this evaluation instead of what you have...

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
<choose>
  <when test="room" != 'null'>
    WHERE B_FLOOR IN
      <foreach collection="room" item="item" index="index" separator="," open="(" close=")AND">
           #{item}
      </foreach>
  </when>
</choose>
```